# Get the $size (length) of a nested array and calculate the difference to a stored value on the parent object - using aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's consider that I have the following documents (ignoring the `_id`):

```
[
  {
    "Id": "Store1",
    "Info": {
      "Location": "Store1 Street",
      "PhoneNumber": 111
    },
    "MaxItemsPerShelf": 3,
    "Shelf": [
      {
        "Id": "Shelf1",
        "Items": [
          {
            "Id": "Item1",
            "Name": "bananas"
          },
          {
            "Id": "Item2",
            "Name": "apples"
          },
          {
            "Id": "Item3",
            "Name": "oranges"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": "Shelf2",
        "Items": [
          {
            "Id": "Item4",
            "Name": "cookies"
          },
          {
            "Id": "Item5",
            "Name": "chocolate"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": "Shelf3",
        "Items": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "Store3",
    "Info": {
      "Location": "Store2 Street",
      "PhoneNumber": 222
    },
    "MaxItemsPerShelf": 2,
    "Shelf": [
      {
        "Id": "Shelf4",
        "Items": [
          {
            "Id": "Item6",
            "Name": "champoo"
          },
          {
            "Id": "Item7",
            "Name": "toothpaste"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": "Shelf5",
        "Items": [
          {
            "Id": "Item8",
            "Name": "chicken"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Given a specific `Shelf.Id` I want to get the following result ( Shelf.Id = "Shelf2"):

```
[{
  "Info": {
    "Location": "Store1 Street",
    "PhoneNumber": 111
  },
  "ItemsNumber": 2,
  "ItemsRemaining": 1
}]
```

Therefore:

- `ItemsNumber`is the `$size` of `Shelf`
  and
- `ItemsRemaining`is equal to  `MaxItemsPerShelf $size` of `Shelf`

also I want to copy the value of the `Info` to the aggregate output.

How can I accomplish this with aggregate? On my efforts I couldn't pass through an *iterator* that gets the `$size` of `$Shelf.Items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "Shelf.Id": "Shelf2" }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "shelf": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$Shelf",
                  "in": {
                    "Id": "$$this.Id",
                    "count": { "$size": "$$this.Items" }
                  }
                }
              },
              "as": "ss",
              "cond": { "$eq": ["$$ss.Id", "Shelf2"] }
            }
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "Info": "$Info",
          "ItemsNumber": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$$shelf.count", 0] },
          "ItemsRemaining": {
            "$subtract": [
              "$MaxItemsPerShelf",
              { "$ifNull": [
                { "$arrayElemAt": ["$$shelf.count", 0] },
                0
              ]}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: As you can see here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/RucCSUtB0t6 the result is not exactly what it was expected. Very very close, still, not the same :)

Comment: Perfect!! Thank's a lot!